# C++: Reading from a file with get(); not working as intended

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a file that looks like the following:

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|                                              |
| |---------|       |--------------|           |
| |.........|       |..............|           |
| |.........|       |..............|           |
| |----+----|       |----+---------|           |
|      #                 #                     |
|      ###################                     |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

(it will be a map file for a game)
In this case, `MAX_WIDTH` is 48 and `MAX_HEIGHT` is 10.

I made it so that it does not skip whitespace when reading with
`infile.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);`

Then I used `get()` in a loop like following:

```
char tile[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH];
char c;

for(int i=0; i<MAX_HEIGHT; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<MAX_WIDTH + 1; j++) {
        infile.get(c);
        if(c == '\n') {
            continue;
        }
        tile[i][j] = c;
    }
}
```

But then after each line, it looked like lines were being pushed when I printed the array.

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|
|| |--------|      |-------------|
|| |........|      |.............|
 || |........|      |.............|
  || |----+---|      |----+--------|
```

Not exact but something like this.

What could've gone wrong and what can I do about it?

(+) Printing the array goes like the following:

```
for(int i=0; y<MAX_HEIGHT; y++) {
    for(int j=0; x<MAX_WIDTH; x++) {
        cout << tile[y][x];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: How are you determining the above output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do you mean?

Comment: Show us the code where you print the array after reading it in.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added the code!

Comment: I figured that making it `for(int j=0; j<MAX_WIDTH + 2; j++)` makes it work but I don't understand why..

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I'm using Sublime Text on Windows and I think I tweaked the option so that linebreaks are in UNIX style but how do I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have windows style linebreaks in your input file you need to read two characters for each linebreak. `\r\n`. That would explain your corrupted output.

A fix would be to use `std::getline` style functions instead of `get`. Or explicitly check for the `\r\n` combination.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be that j < MAX_WIDTH + 1

since your first line is good, probelm start happen in your second row

try remove that + 1

Edit:

1. remove that +1
2. you may try to is to add a check on both \r \n when reading

Comment: That makes it so that it is pushed even further.

Comment: Making it + 2 makes it work but I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: there could be \r or \n depends on the OS you using

Comment: Using Sublime Text on Windows and compiling on Linux (using PuTTY)

Comment: Just curious, have your problem get fixed?